# Password hashing in Django

Tags: django, passwords, vbulletin

I'm trying to integrate vBulliten and Django's user databases. I know vB uses a md5 algorithm to hash it's passwords, with a salt. I have the salt data and the password for each vB user, and would like to know how to import those accounts onto Django.

I've tried the obvious, changing the Django user's password to;

md5$vb's_salt$vb's_password

This just throws back Django's log-in form, with a message saying "username and password does not match"

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a vBulletin entry for a known password (e.g. "password" :)  Then we can help more easily, and perhaps even come up with some custom code to allow this.

Answer (score 2):

You could either update passwords from db manually, or write some Python.

> The password attribute of a User object is a string in this format:
>
> `hashtype$salt$hash`
>
> That's hashtype, salt and hash, separated by the dollar-sign character.
>
> Hashtype is either sha1 (default), md5 or crypt -- the algorithm used to perform a one-way hash of the password. Salt is a random string used to salt the raw password to create the hash. Note that the crypt method is only supported on platforms that have the standard Python crypt module available.
>
> For example:
>
> `sha1$a1976$a36cc8cbf81742a8fb52e221aaeab48ed7f58ab4`
>
> The set_password() and check_password() functions handle the setting and checking of these values behind the scenes.

(reference: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#passwords)

Comment: exalted, given my above comment on stefanw's reply, would you suggest that the failure is because I haven't used django's user object methods to change the password for the test user? Thanks again for your input.

Comment: I'd suggest you updating database manually for a single user and see if he can login only after that. Not sure about the admin interface.

Answer (score 1):

Obvious first question: How did you change the user's password? You need to put the algo$salt$password string directly into the database.

It's probable that vBulleting uses another way to create the password hash from the password and salt. If this is the case, you may have to implement an alternative login that checks the user password differently and then stores it in the Django format.

Comment: stefanw, thanks for the input. I added the password to the database via the admin section of the site. You know the password box that shows your password in the format algo$salt$password? This was done as a one-off by hand to check if it would work. The intention is eventually to write a Python script to do this instead.

Answer (score 1):

vBulletin doesn't salt and hash the password the same way as Django.

vBulletin does it like this:

```
$hash_stored_in_database = md5(md5($plaintext_password) . $salt);
```